# Tradingview pine script coding

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, wma, rsi

everyone,
I want to code WMA below Panel like rsi, upper range 100, lower range 0. samelike rsi.
How can i add it to WMA coding?

```
//@version=5

indicator(title="Moving Average Weighted3", shorttitle="WMA", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)


len = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Length")

srca = input(close, title="Source")

offset = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-1500, maxval=1500)

out = ta.wma(srca, len)

plot(out, title="WMA", color=color.blue, offset=offset)
```

Answer (score 1):

To put it below like rsi, change overlay from true to false-> overlay=false